# How to link DHCP server to SQL database?

Tags: sql, dhcp

Our project is about taking attendance using WiFi. Students will use their smartphones to connect with our router TP-LINK. Once they are connected to our router their MAC address will be listed in DHCP client. We already created a simple database where the idea is student MAC addresses will link to database. In our database of MAC addresses each student is already in there. So the question is how to link the MAC address from DHCP to database SQL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you asking how to get MACs from the DHCP client, how to look up matching strings in SQL, both, or neither? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: ... So if you forget your phone, or the battery dies, or you just don't have a phone that connects to WiFi networks, you're considered absent, even though you sat in class all day?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Eypeyelester Zeno,

I would say the best Method is to use **OpenWRT** if you aren't already doing so.

Just flash the TP-Link router with **OpenWRT** and you can use basic Linux Shell scripts to scrape and save the MAC address.

Assuming that you are familiar with PHP and MYSQL.

You can simply use **Netcat** built into OpenWRT to send the MAC address to an HTML/PHP post page, which would then send to your SQL database.

If you would like more detailed explanation let me know, I've done the exact same thing to send Ping Latency to an SQL database.

It's probably the easiest method with as little code and no socket programming.